# Calculating the height and width of a div and relating that to the window height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am setting up a gallery that will contain a set amount of columns and each column will possess a varying amount of elements within them. The logic is that you hover around the window width and height and are able to view the containing div relative to the height and width. I have managed to get the dynamic width of the element and successfully maneuver the div to so every column is visible - as you can see in the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/x66zqwaa/ (the jquery is underneath). What I don't understand is that horizontally i'm able to view each element successfully - but vertically some of the divs are cut off and it isn't behaving in the same way as it does horizontally. If anyone could please assist i'd be very grateful!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var winW = $(window).width(),
  winH = $(window).height(),
  winWHalf = winW / 2,
  winHHalf = winH / 2,
  $cont = $(".content"),
  contW = $cont.width(),
  contH = $cont.height(),
  diffX = (winW - contW) /2,
  diffY = (winH - contH) /2;

var finalX = 0,
    finalY = 0;

var moveContent = function(e) {

var x = e.pageX,
    y = e.pageY;

finalX = ((x) * (contW / winW) / 2);
finalY = ((y) * (contH / winH) / 2);

console.log(finalX, finalY);
  $cont.css("transform", "translate3D(" + (0 - finalX) + "px, " + (0 - finalY) + "px, 0)");

}; $(document).ready(function() {

var winW = $(window).width(),
  winH = $(window).height(),
  winWHalf = winW / 2,
  winHHalf = winH / 2,
  $cont = $(".content"),
  contW = $cont.width(),
  contH = $cont.height(),
  diffX = (winW - contW) /2,
  diffY = (winH - contH) /2;

var finalX = 0,
    finalY = 0;

var moveContent = function(e) {

var x = e.pageX,
    y = e.pageY;

finalX = ((x) * (contW / winW) / 2);
finalY = ((y) * (contH / winH) / 2);

console.log(finalX, finalY);
  $cont.css("transform", "translate3D(" + (0 - finalX) + "px, " + (0 - finalY) + "px, 0)");

};
```

Apologies but for some reason i'm not able to post the entirity of the code. Please see the fiddle.

Comment: I don't quite understand, you want your main div to span the entirety of the window, given it's outer size? Also, $(window) would grab your screen dimensions over $(document) which is your actual viewport on the device etc.

Comment: Sorry - my original question probably wasn't clear. The idea of the experiment is that the window height and width is relative to the (dynamic) height and width of the .content div. That way when you hover to the top right of the window you are able to view the top right of the .content div. I have this working horizontally - as you can see, but my issue is when you hover to the bottom of the window you're not able to fully see the bottom of the .content div. Hope this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating `width` and `height` based on `$(".content")`. You need to use either `$(window)` or `$(document)` instead. For `height`, you might want to use the bigger value, to make sure that you fill the screen.

Comment: Sorry - my original question probably wasn't clear. The idea of the experiment is that the window height and width is relative to the (dynamic) height and width of the .content div. That way when you hover to the top right of the window you are able to view the top right of the .content div. I have this working horizontally - as you can see, but my issue is when you hover to the bottom of the window you're not able to fully see the bottom of the .content div. Hope this makes more sense.